# Swift Package Manager, but not a git repo

Tags: swift-package-manager

I have a file system for a Swift project which has a Package.swift.

I need to be able to import this project as an SPM package into another project.

But this project is stored as just files on a server which can be accessed via GET requests. There is no git server, unfortunately.

Is it possible to host an SPM module on a server that is not a git server?